# Will I be able to map IIS virtual directory to Azure CDN in the cloud?

Tags: azure, iis, azure-cdn

Will there be a way for us to use Azure as nothing but file storage and CDN, then somehow map a virtual directory to the Azure space?

Answer (score 2):

No longer true.  Azure now offers a Content Delivery Network.  Please see:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazure/archive/2009/11/05/introducing-the-windows-azure-content-delivery-network.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You could use Windows Azure blob storage and then do redirects. For example, you could CNAME your domain to youraccount.blob.core.windows.net. Or you could send down HTTP 302s from your virtual directory to the right blob URI.

In either case, the blob storage will do the heavylifting in terms of scaling, etc. Note that Windows Azure currently doesn't have any CDN features (as in - routing DCs based on source IP, geo-load-balancing, etc). If you want to control the geography of where your data is, create your storage account and put it in an affinity group set to a location close to your users